# How do I remove the action attribute from a Rails form_for form builder/helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I need to create a custom rails `form_for` helper that writes out a clientside form for a model object. The clientside framework requires that I don't have an action in the form tag or the the form will submit to the action. how do I remove it? I want to avoid manipulating on the client side if I can and just remove the action attribute. I have a custom form builder that controls the output of form fields and following is how I am rendering the tag. I am stuck for how to do this anyone have any ideas?

```
  def angular_form_for record, *args, &block
    options = args.extract_options!
    options[:builder] = AngularFormFor::FormBuilder
    options[:html] ||= {}
    options[:html]['novalidate'] = 'novalidate'
    options[:html]['name'] = 'form'
    form_for record, *(args << options), &block
  end
```

So if I call it in the view with:

```
angular_form_for @order do |f|
  ...
end
```

This gives me output similar to this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/orders" id="new_order" method="post" name="form" novalidate="novalidate">
....
</form>
```

What I want is something like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="new_order" method="post" name="form" novalidate="novalidate">
....
</form>
```

Comment: Is this impossible? Is what I am asking unclear?

Comment: FYI I am facing the same problem as you. `action` attribute is forbidden with AMP. So I am building manually the `form` tag for now.

Answer (score 2):

So I was having a similar problem and here is how I finally solved it.

For angularjs 1.2, it's enough to set action to blank

```
form_for(@my_model,:url=>'')
```

For angularjs 1.3, you have to set action to something like this

```
form_for(@my_model,:url=>'javascript:;')
```

I am not sure if this is valid html, or best practices, but it does work.